# Code Coverage with SonarQube 6.3, Sonar Scanner 2.9 and Maven-2

Tags: sonarqube, maven-2

Is it possible to calculate code coverage with maven 2 and sonar scanner 2.8/2.9?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but Sonar Scanner is not responsible for generating code coverage. It only process reports generated by other tools, e.g.:

- [EclEmma JaCoCo Java Code Coverage Library](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/)
- [Atlassian Clover](https://www.atlassian.com/software/clover)
- [Cobertura](http://cobertura.github.io/cobertura/)
- ...

Example how to use JaCoCo with Java Plugin: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Usage+of+JaCoCo+with+Java+Plugin

Comment: So far I know, is Cobertura and JaCoCo not compatible with SQ 6.3.

Comment: I have SonarQube 6.3 and it shows code coverage provided by JaCoCo.